# How to enable/disable the result of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, marker

I have a function that reads my markers from a file and outputs them into my map.
This is my function:

```
function showResourcesByName(name) {
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.resources.length; i++) {
                    var resName = markers.resources[i].name;

                    if (resName == name) {
                        var resIcon = icons.resources[i].icon;
                        var resSize = icons.resources[i].size;
                        var resPname = icons.resources[i].pname;

                        var customIcon = L.icon({
                            iconUrl: resIcon,
                            iconSize: resSize, // size of the icon
                            iconAnchor:   [resSize[0]/2, resSize[1]/2], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                            popupAnchor:  [2, -resSize[1]/2] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                        });

                        for (var j = 0; j < markers.resources[i].coords.length; j++) {
                            var x = markers.resources[i].coords[j].x;
                            var y = markers.resources[i].coords[j].y;

                            marker = L.marker([y, x], {icon: customIcon});
                            marker.addTo(map).bindPopup(resPname);
                            $(marker._icon).addClass('chutiya')



                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

To show my markers I use the function like this:

```
showResourcesByName("AITokarServer");
showResourcesByName("AIBorServer");
```

If I comment the result like this: `//showResourcesByName("AITokarServer");`
The markers disappear.

My problem is that I have 5950 markers, from 29 groups, and all of them load once the page is loaded.

I want to make a checkbox that enable/disable the result of that function just like I can enable and disable it by commenting.
Is it possible?

My temporary workaround was to toggle the markers on/off using css classes (each marker have a class with its group name):

```
$('#shigitoggle').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) 
    //  ^
$('.AIShigiServer').fadeOut('slow');
    else 
$('.AIShigiServer').fadeIn('slow');
```

});

The problem is that when they are "off" they still in the code, making the page slower (I say that because there are 5950 markers in the code).

You can see my full code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/s5xUx9LQcwYP3g3Cx7MX?p=preview

Comment: You're going to have to simply remove them, if you expect to make it less laggy. You already have the file and the information, so reapplying them later shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I cannot remove them, I need a way to toggle them on/off similar to the add layer/remove layer from leaflet. You can check the map live here: www.hurtworldmap.com then you will understand why I cannot remove them, they are the main information for the map.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I have 5950 markers, from 29 groups, and all of them load once the page is loaded.

Use [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) to not show all markers at once.

> The problem is that when they are "off" they still in the code, making the page slower (I say that because there are 5950 markers in the code).

No. Having 6000 items in data structures and wasting a bit of memory is not the problem. Having 6000 **visible DOM elements** in your webpage is the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately because the way the markers are pulled I cannot use leaflet.markercluster, or I don't know how, I tried and no luck. I am thinking  about using .prepend and detach.

Comment: You just have to do `marker.addTo(cluster)` instead of `marker.addTo(map)`.

Comment: Yes. Read the plugin documentation and experiment with it.